# GroupBy with sub-ranges in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, machine-learning

I am researching soccer dataset

```
   LEAGUE   HOME    DRAW    AWAY    WINNER  PREDICTED   PROFIT
0   2       3.25    3.25    2.10       0           2    -10.0
1   14      1.50    3.50    6.00       0           0    5.0
2   2       2.25    3.30    3.20       2           0    -10.0
3   11      2.25    3.00    2.88       0           0    12.5
4   17      5.00    3.75    1.70       2           2    7.0
```

Now, I am looking for approach `GroupBy(League, 1.25 < Home < 1.5 | 1.5 < Home < 1.75 ..)` and get target dataset as on example:

```
   LEAGUE     HOME    PROFIT
0   2       1.25-1.5    10.0
1   2       1.50-1.75    5.0
2   3         NaN        NaN
3   3       1.5-1.75    12.5
...
```

Comment: sounds like you want to do a [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html)

Comment: Any example would be great :). I am using `pandas_ml` and looks like this library doesn't support that function `AttributeError: 'ModelFrame' object has no attribute 'qcut'`

Comment: it should be simple, call `qcut` pass your df column and pass a list of the boundaries and then filter the df

Comment: Maybe you can try: `bins = np.linspace(0, 5, 20, endpoint=False)` and `print df.groupby([df.LEAGUE, pd.cut(df.HOME, bins)]).sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins = np.linspace(0, 5, 20, endpoint=False)
print bins
[ 0.    0.25  0.5   0.75  1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.    2.25  2.5   2.75
  3.    3.25  3.5   3.75  4.    4.25  4.5   4.75]

print df.groupby([df.LEAGUE, pd.cut(df.HOME, bins)]).sum()
```

```
                    HOME  DRAW  AWAY  WINNER  PREDICTED  PROFIT
LEAGUE HOME                                                    
2      (0, 0.25]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (0.25, 0.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (0.5, 0.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (0.75, 1]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (1, 1.25]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (1.25, 1.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (1.5, 1.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (1.75, 2]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (2, 2.25]    2.25  3.30  3.20       2          0   -10.0
       (2.25, 2.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (2.5, 2.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (2.75, 3]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (3, 3.25]    3.25  3.25  2.10       0          2   -10.0
       (3.25, 3.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (3.5, 3.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (3.75, 4]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (4, 4.25]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (4.25, 4.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (4.5, 4.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
11     (0, 0.25]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (0.25, 0.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (0.5, 0.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (0.75, 1]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (1, 1.25]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (1.25, 1.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (1.5, 1.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (1.75, 2]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (2, 2.25]    2.25  3.00  2.88       0          0    12.5
       (2.25, 2.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (2.5, 2.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
...                  ...   ...   ...     ...        ...     ...
14     (2, 2.25]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (2.25, 2.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (2.5, 2.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (2.75, 3]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (3, 3.25]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (3.25, 3.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (3.5, 3.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (3.75, 4]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (4, 4.25]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (4.25, 4.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (4.5, 4.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
17     (0, 0.25]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (0.25, 0.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (0.5, 0.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (0.75, 1]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (1, 1.25]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (1.25, 1.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (1.5, 1.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (1.75, 2]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (2, 2.25]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (2.25, 2.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (2.5, 2.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (2.75, 3]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (3, 3.25]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (3.25, 3.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (3.5, 3.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (3.75, 4]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (4, 4.25]     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (4.25, 4.5]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN
       (4.5, 4.75]   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN        NaN     NaN

[76 rows x 6 columns]
```

EDIT:

You can use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
print df.groupby([df.LEAGUE, pd.cut(df.HOME, bins)]).agg({'HOME' : min, 
                                                          'DRAW' : min, 
                                                          'AWAY' : min, 
                                                          'WINNER' : 'count', 
                                                          'PREDICTED' : 'count', 
                                                          'PROFIT': sum})

                    DRAW  PROFIT  AWAY  WINNER  PREDICTED  HOME
LEAGUE HOME                                                    
2      (2, 2.25]    3.30   -10.0  3.20       1          1  2.25
       (3, 3.25]    3.25   -10.0  2.10       1          1  3.25
11     (2, 2.25]    3.00    12.5  2.88       1          1  2.25
14     (1.25, 1.5]  3.50     5.0  6.00       1          1  1.50
```

Comment: Side question - Does it possible to `group` columns [home, draw, away] by `min`, columns [winner, predicted] by `count` and rest by `sum` ?