# python way to groupby given sub levels of interest

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions

given a pandas data frame like the following, i would like to do some kind of groupby on 'users' but with a special defined sub-criteria on the time column summing the amount column.

```
   amount  time users
0      11     0     A
1      23    10     A
2      12    20     A
3      34    30     A
4      56    40     B
5      77    50     B
6      89    60     C
```

for this i have pairs of range_start and range_end for example in a list of tuples or similar. these sub_group_ranges for the time column should enable me to apply a groupby().sum on each batch within the data frame.

```
sub_group_ranges = [(0,0),(20,30),(40,50),(60,60)]
```

The result should look like the following. The count of intervals per user is arbitrary.

```
   sum_amount_on_timerange user
0                       57    A
1                      133    B
2                       89    C
```

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610563/groupby-with-sub-ranges-in-pandas) to be similar yet i don't understand on how to work with it if i dont have consecutive intervals meaning where the end of the first interval is not the beginning of the following interval.

Would be greatful if someone has an idea on what to look for.
Thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do but here is something that might work

```
df = pd.DataFrame([users,time]).T
df.columns = ['users','time']

def filter_time_range(ele,trange):
    if (ele>trange[0]) and (ele<=trange[1]):
        return ele
    else:
        return np.nan
   
sub_group_ranges = [(0,0),(20,30),(40,50),(60,60)]
for trange in sub_group_ranges:
    df[str(trange)] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: filter_time_range(x,trange))
    
df
```

resulting in

```
  users time    (0, 0)  (20, 30)    (40, 50)    (60, 60)
0   A   0        NaN     NaN           NaN      NaN
1   A   10       NaN     NaN           NaN      NaN
2   A   20       NaN     NaN           NaN      NaN
3   A   30       NaN     30.0           NaN     NaN
4   B   40       NaN     NaN           NaN      NaN
5   B   50       NaN     NaN           50.0     NaN
6   C   60       NaN     NaN           NaN      NaN
```

along with your user grouping

```
df.groupby(['users']).sum()


  (0, 0)    (20, 30)    (40, 50)    (60, 60)
users               
A     0.0    30.0   0.0     0.0
B     0.0    0.0    50.0    0.0
C     0.0    0.0    0.0     0.0
```

I've excluded `amount` from my dataframe

Comment: Hi @will.cass.wrig, thanks for the quick reply. the summation of the amount would be what should be the returned value. First i intend to groupby the users. The second operation would to only chose the rows that are covered by the range definition given by sub_group_ranges which apply only within one user group.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for the second operation but I believe the final table in my solution answers this question. You can then consolidate the solution into a single column if needed by adding the pandas columns together.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I had to adapt it a bit to do what i wanted exactly but it works nicely. Basically made it apply to the whole dataframe so being able to chose the amount column. 

`def filter_time_range2(df_ele,trange):`<br/> 
`    if (df_ele['time']>=trange[0]) and (df_ele['time']<=trange[1]):`
        return df_ele['amount']
    else:
        return np.nan`